# Facebook Iframe Scroll Bar Issue on Chrome

Tags: facebook, iframe, scrollbar

I'm using a facebook app as a tab on a facebook page.
The problem I'm having is with removing the scroll bars that appear around the iframe,
specifically with Google Chrome on a Mac running Lion. The fix that works for all the other browsers doesn't seem to work! Has anyone else noticed this problem?

Sorry for not being specific. I have accordions that expand down making the frame bigger. I have set the height of the app to fluid. All the other browsers are showing it correctly. It is just chrome on Mac OS X Lion. The javascript I'm using is.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
        }
```

I would also like to add that OS X Lion has different looking scrollbars...I don't know if this would change anything.

Just realised the same problem occurs on the latest firefox on windows xp, if I refresh, it sometimes goes away and comes back. The scroll bars aren't showing but the content is cropped at 800px and I can scroll through it.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    width: 520px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**FB.Canvas.setAutoResize** will be removed on January 1st, 2012, use **FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow** instead.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/

Comment: Thanks! but this hasn't fixed the problem. :(

Comment: did you set your css like this?

body {
                width:520px;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                border:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                }

Comment: Thanks for your help. The sidebars are not showing anymore but the frame won't grow with the content I'm using AutoGrow and I've set the height to fixed 800. Still strictly Chrome on OS X Lion.